# Out of range. How to add the remainder of list to accumulator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, accumulator

I get [-7,-4,-2], but I want to add the remaining numbers to my accumulator but I keep going out of range in my second if statement. How would I continue to add the remaining list?
input:  interleaved( [-7, -2, -1], [-4, 0, 4, 8])

```
def interleaved(seq1,seq2):
i = 0
j = 0
res = []

    

while i <len(seq1) and j <len(seq2):
    if seq1[i] < seq2[j]:
        res.append(seq1[i])
        i+=1
    if  seq2[j] <= seq1[i]:
        res.append(seq2[j])
        j+=1
return res
```

Comment: Well, in your second if statement, (i) will eventually equal 3, and seq1 can go up to index 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added an `if` statement to check whether we "finished" exploring `seq1` or not (same `if` "check" can be applied on `seq2` in case it had more negative values than `seq1`)

```
def interleaved(seq1, seq2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    res = []

    while i < len(seq1) and j < len(seq2):
        if seq1[i] < seq2[j]:
            res.append(seq1[i])
            i += 1
            if i == len(seq1):  # If we explored all of seq1 (reached the end)
                for num in seq2[j:]:  # Explore the rest of seq2
                    res.append(num)  # Append the rest
                break  # Break the while loop and go to "return"
        if seq2[j] <= seq1[i]:
            res.append(seq2[j])
            j += 1

    return res

print(interleaved())
```